# How to get PHP to minify JS and CSS code?

Tags: php, javascript, css, minify

I'm looking for a PHP class that can minify JS and CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tested it, but this looks quite promising: [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

Comment: We just implemented this and I have to admit that the saving in bandwidth and size improvement has been amazing. And this is based on my uber-fast (ya right) connection of 20mbps

Answer (score 0):

I've found one over, in case anyone wants to take a look. Its called [SmartOptimizer](http://farhadi.ir/works/smartoptimizer), and I think is pretty good!