# Is there a min. version of the jquery datepicker javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I want to know if there is a min. version of the jquery datepicker javascript file

Comment: Finally, I found the minified version of each of the widgets, along with its uncompressed version. I downloaded version 1.7.2 from this following link : http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-1.7.2.zip, and all the themes from the themeroller is available at : http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/files/jquery-ui-themes-1.7.2.0.zip. The download page link is : http://blog.jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know, but why not minimize it yourself?

With scripts that are not distributed in a minified version by the authors, minifying it yourself is safer than downloading a minified version from a third party. Also you don't have to wait until one pops up for the latest version of your script.

I've not used it myself yet, but [**Minify**](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is in good standing, judging from other SO questions.

Related SO resources with good links to more tools:

- **[YUICompressor or similar in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972757/yuicompressor-or-similar-in-php)**
- [**can any one help me in getting php class to min js and css codes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212720/can-any-one-help-me-in-getting-php-class-to-min-js-and-css-codes)

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from http://jqueryui.com/download